# Best practice for using Jupyter in VSCode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-remote

I am using VSCode to connect to a remote server using SSH. Due to the particular process of port-forwarding which is necessary to connect to the server, I cannot avoid the connection to be interrupted from time to time, eg when the local computer sleeps. Reconnection works reasonably well for working with python files and remote processes running in tmux.

However, when working with Jupyter notebooks (whose jupyter process is also running in a tmux to be persistent), I am regularly running into the problem that the window won't reconnect as it says my notebook has unsaved changes if VSCode got disconnected during running a process in Jupyter. The notebook is preventing the server from reconnecting, it can't be saved to the remote server (as it's disconnected), nor locally (doesn't work), so any changes will be lost.

Any insight how to optimize this process?

TL,DR: I would like to have a persistent Jupyter session that will just reconnect to the last state on reconnection.
However, the "unsaved changes" are preventing VSCode from reconnecting, and changes may be lost.